# How to update all rows of matching query?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the following code:

```
for loop:
   col.update(
                {"name" : "abc", "mvr_code" : mvr_code)},
                {'$set': { "reaction": reaction}}
                )
```

my db looks something like this:

```
{name:'abc', mvr_code:1}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:1}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:2}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:2}
```

after running the code i get this:

```
{name:'abc', mvr_code:1, reaction:'r1'}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:1}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:2, reaction:'r2'}
{name:'abc', mvr_code:2}
```

How do i make it work for all the cases and not just the first one?

Comment: You want to make it work on duplicate item also right?

Comment: yes i want it to work for all duplicates too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `multi: true` to the query. 
As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-multi), the `multi` parameter is a boolean and if set to true, updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria. If set to false, updates one document. The default value is false.

The query could be redone as :

```
db.test1.update({name : "abc", mvr_code : 1},{$set: { "reacttion":1}}, multi:true)
```

Let me know if it helpa!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The correct format is: 
`db.test1.update({name : "abc", mvr_code : 1},{$set: { "reacttion":1}}, multi:True)`.
Please make the correction for others